# Post fails from android using webApi

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a simple android app that sends the name and phonenumber using POST in a JSON format to a webApi MVC4 in asp.net and using SQL server for the database. The problem is I can't seem to get it right and it never posts anything to my database when I send information to the webapi.

It has worked when I send the JSON using fiddler, but I don't understand what the problem is. Please help, I've been stuck for a while now.

here is my Jquery ajax client code:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {"Name" : "JUJI", "PhoneNumber" : 999},
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:52380/api/Default1",
      dataType: "json",
      success:function(response){
        alert("yupie");
        console.log(response);
    },
    error:function(response){
        alert("no response");
        console.log(response);
    }
    });
```

Here is my Model code on the server side in webApi:

```
public class Contact
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double PhoneNumber { get; set; }

}
```

My controller on my server side:

```
// POST api/Default1
        public HttpResponseMessage PostContact(Contact contact)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.Contacts.Add(contact);
                db.SaveChanges();

                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, contact);
                response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = contact.ID }));
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you running the server on the same machine as android emulator then use 10.0.2.2 as the server IP.

Comment: Hey that worked, Thanks a lot!! :D Just a question why the 10.0.2.2 ip address?

Comment: please accept the answer it it worked... The android emulator works this way more can be found at following link http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Answer (score 0):

You are making your call to localhost (127.0.0.1) which in this case refers to the device or emulator you are running the code on. So the phone is trying to talk to itself and obviously your server side code does not run on the device. You'll need to replace 127.0.0.1 with the ip address or server name of the PC that runs your servlet.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I changed the ip address but I didn't receive a response. Before when I had the localhost address I got an error response and now nothing seems to happen. I am testing my android emulator on eclipse.